# Is there a quality "adept"?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Working myself though the quick start rules, I notice that the archetype *combat adept* has a quality *adept*. Looking at the core rulebook, I did not find *adept* in the list of qualities on page 73.

My first Idea was that this is just referring to the fact that the character is an adept. Crosschecking that with the archetype from the core rulebook that seems not the case. the *brawling adept* does not have *adept* as a quality (page. 117) but the *gunslinger adept* (page 123) has.

So I am wondering, where can I find an explanation of the *adept* qualities? What does it involve and is it a positive or negative one?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.StackExchange.com!  Good first question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were correct in your first assumption. There is no Adept quality. The "Adept" quality is simply referring to the fact that the character is an Adept. The fact that it is listed in the "Qualities" instead of listed in some other less confusing place is probably a carryover from back in 4th edition when you DID have to purchase a quality to be an Adept (or a Magician, for that matter).

Why is it listed in the Gunslinger Adept archetype and not on the Brawler Adept? My guess is that it's simply an oversight.

Answer (score 4):

There is no quality "adept" in Shadowrun 5, the French version correct this. 
And the Brawling Adept has quality "Pain Resistance (1)" but that should be "High Pain Tolerance 1". (in errata thread in dumpshock : http://forums.dumpshock.com/lofiversion/index.php/t39006-200.html)

Answer (score -3):

No the adept is still in the game but adept magician and mystic adept are no longer qualities but you get them at character creation in the priority system. Easiest way to tell the differnce on your character sheet is if they have spells powers or both